# Creating an OAuth2.0 provider in python 3 for an existing WSGI server

Tags: python, oauth

I cannot figure out how to create an OAuth v. 2.0 provider for my existing wsgi server.
I want to deploy a custom OAuth 2.0 provider on my existing wsgi-server (using apache's mod_wsgi) over HTTPS. The wsgi basis and HTTPS are already implemented and working fine.
Unfortunately I could only find [this tutorial](https://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/server.html) for oauthlib on how to implement OAuth 2.0 providers in python 3.
But this very modules' documentation mostly refers to frameworks like drango and flask, which I don't need and thus don't want to use for this very project.
Additionally, the oauthlib seems to force me using their own webserver as described in

```
# From the previous section on validators
from my_validator import MyRequestValidator

from oauthlib.oauth2 import WebApplicationServer

validator = MyRequestValidator()
server = WebApplicationServer(validator)
```

My problem here is, that I want to create an OAuth 2.0 provider without the mentioned frameworks on my existing WSGI server, but cannot figure out where I need to change what.

Answer (score 2):

WebApplicationServer is *"An all-in-one endpoint featuring Authorization code grant and Bearer tokens."*. Pythons oauthlib is not tied to any particular type of transport in the sense that you provide the "server" with parameters needed to validate a request, and the server uses the provided validator to do so. In return you will get a response that you need to provide to the requestee.

Commonly you map HTTP paths and methods to the servers functions, for example GET /authorize could map to server.validate_authorization_request (provided by AuthorizationEndpoint). Given there are no errors in the request, you would use the return value to render a form where the user can consent to providing an authorization code to the client.

Most effort will be spent in creating an implementation of a RequestValidator. This is where oauthlib will figure out if a client exists, which scopes are considered valid, persisting authorization codes and so forth.